# Make a docked phone on a stand showing inbox

Tags: gmail, google-pixel, docking-station

How do I make my Android phone on the stand show my inbox (Gmail, mobile website, or even the Outlook app if need be)?

While I'm working, I like having my entire computer dedicated to that, probably a number of apps, a number of tabs, etc.

I have an Android phone (Pixel 7P) that I have on a (Pixel) stand next to my computer screen. It shows the time, weather, and family photos, but want I would really like to see is if my boss sends me an email.

Is there a way to keep the Gmail app visible? Or a widget or something that shows incoming emails.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting about the possibility of the [*docked state*](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/161752/44325), so I'm not sure whether answers about kiosk mode/app pinning or widget on the home screen might be applicable on this case.